# How bash handles the jobs when logout?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

As far as I understood from the books and bash manuals is that. When a user logs out from bash all the background jobs that is started by the user will automatically terminate, if he is not using nohup or disown. But today I tested it :

1. Logged in to my gnome desktop and accessed gnome-terminal.
2. There are two tabs in the terminal and in one I created a new user called test and logged in as test

   ```
   su - test
   ```
3. started a script.

   ```
   cat test.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   sleep 60
   printf "hello world!!"
   exit 0


   ./test.sh &
   ```
4. After that I logged out of test and closed the tab
5. In the next tab I exected ps aux as root and found that job is still running.

How this is happening ?

Comment: I noticed that this question does not yet have an accepted answer and that there is a similar new question on [SU] which might be interesting reading: [http://superuser.com/questions/662431/what-exactly-determines-if-a-backgrounded-job-is-killed-when-the-shell-is-exited](http://superuser.com/questions/662431/what-exactly-determines-if-a-backgrounded-job-is-killed-when-the-shell-is-exited)

Answer (score 19):

Whether running background jobs are terminated on exit depends on the shell. Bash normally does not do this, but can be configured to for login shells (`shopt -s huponexit`). In any case, access to the tty is impossible after the controlling process (such as a login shell) has terminated.

Situations that do always cause `SIGHUP` include:

- Anything in foreground when the tty is closed down.
- Any background job that includes stopped processes when their shell terminates (`SIGCONT` and `SIGHUP`). Shells typically warn you before letting this happen.

huponexit summary:

- **On**: Background jobs will be terminated with SIGHUP when shell exits

  ```
  $ shopt -s huponexit
  $ shopt huponexit
  huponexit       on
  ```
- **Off**: Background jobs will NOT be terminated with SIGHUP when shell exits.

  ```
  $ shopt -u huponexit
  $ shopt huponexit
  huponexit       off
  ```

Comment: so you are saying that, if huponexit option is not set then bash will not kill the background jobs of users ?

Comment: @Unni – If `huponexit` is set, Bash will send SIGHUP to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits ( with either  **exit**  or  **Ctrl + d** ).

Answer (score 3):

Only interactive shells kill jobs when you close them. Other shells (for example those you get by using `su - username`) don't do that. And interactive shells only kill direct subprocesses.

Comment: What is interactive shell ?  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html says that, if $PS1 is set then it is an interactive shell. Also I switched to another tty using ctrl+alt+f2 and logged in as test and done same thing. result is same but.

Comment: `su - username` gives you an interactive shell.