# How to open java program in other linux computer without terminal holding?

Tags: java, linux

I have written a java program with jar file. The java program is to update status of linux server so it need to keep running, but the linux server is in data center, so I need to remote to server to open the program. I use ssh to login linux server. Use command of "java -jar file.jar" to run the program.

However, the java program of the linux server will close if I close the terminal in my computer. Since I cannot keep opening my computer, I wanna know how to open the java programming without holding my computer terminal.

Comment: You may use a cron task

Comment: Duplicate, see the post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `nohup` to keep the program running after you log out.:

```
server:~name$> nohup java -jar file.jar &
```

this will keep your program running

Comment: Here is the response: "nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'"

Comment: thats fine, it says that any `System.out.println()` will go to file named nohup.out

Answer (score 2):

Two ways

One

```
nohup java -jar file.jar &
```

Another

```
java -jar file.jar &
```

In both cases your process will go in background however the process will terminate in the second approach when shell terminates in second case.

Comment: Here is the response: "nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'"

Comment: That is perfectly fine your stdout will be redirected to nohup.out. Point is did your process go into background, or it did not?

Answer (score 0):

If this program is intended to be running on all your machines for monitoring purposes, you should be running it as a service from your server's init system (`systemd` for most systems these days). You can use the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) or [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) or write your own init script.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution apart from the proposed one:

```
screen -d -m java -jar your.jar
```

You will then have a detached screen with your `java` command in it. List with `screen -l`, reattach with `screen -D -RR <screenid_obtained_via_screen_-ls>`