# Running multiple Java Applications on startup

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, server

I currently run these java applications with the following command via root:
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar /var/www/tekkit.socialnetwk.com/tekkit.jar nogui

Although if I close the terminal window those applications close/stop.
Is there anyway to stop this from happening? Either creating it as a service or to start it on boot.
I've tried rc.local but no luck.

I'm running on Ubuntu - Newest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I have done two things to make a process run after the terminal shuts down... use ampersand to run it in the background and nohup so that it does not get killed by the terminal closing.

```
nohup java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar /var/www/tekkit.socialnetwk.com/tekkit.jar nogui &
```

EDIT:  [Here is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595391/1490322) that goes into detail.  Upvote that answer instead since it is way more complete.

Comment: you may want to also redirect both outputs into a file by `&>> logfile`. So: `nohup java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar /var/www/tekkit.socialnetwk.com/tekkit.jar nogui &>> logfile &`

Comment: Should I get this output? nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

Comment: First, hopefully your Java process has good logging that you can rely on.  You can either get comfortable with viewing nohop.out or if you want the stdout/stderr to go to a different file then use the redirect that @JiriKremser suggested.