# How to run bash script without terminate

Tags: php, bash, terminal

When i run this script via terminal on my dedicated server it works. But only while the window is opened (the terminal). When i close the window, it close the script for running. How can i make it running forever in the background?

`#!/bin/bash
    ./robots.sh &
    ./update_robots.sh &
    ./update_auctions_end.sh &
    ./auto_bidders.sh`

Comment: Put `&` at the end when running the script

Comment: See: [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/3776858) or [Linux: Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/3776858) and [What's the difference between nohup and ampersand](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15595374/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the "nohup" command to do something like this:

```
nohup ./robots.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Hope this helps you.

You can see full details of nohup here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup

Comment: Like this? #!/bin/bash
 nohup ./robots.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
 nohup ./update_robots.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
 nohup ./update_auctions_end.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
 nohup  ./auto_bidders.sh &

Answer (score 0):

try sending output to null, then your command window will not wait for output and will leave the process alone with itself:

```
command params > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```