# Multiple exec in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, exec, sh

What happens if you have multiple `exec` commands in a shell script, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec yes > /dev/null &
exec yes alex > /dev/null
```

I assume that a fork is still needed in order to execute the first command since the shell needs to continue executing?

Or does the `&` specify to create a sub process in which the exec is actually then run?

Comment: Consider [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/201200) if your question is answered!

Answer (score 3):

The use of `&` implie a sub-process.

So `exec` have no effect.

Demo:

```
export LANG=C
echo $$
17259
exec sh -c 'echo $$;read foo' &
[1] 17538
17538

[1]+  Stopped                 exec sh -c 'echo $$;read foo'   
fg

exec sh -c 'echo $$;read foo'  
17259
```

I run the script: `echo $$;read foo` in order to prevent exit before having quietly read previous output.

In this sample, the current process ID is *`17259`*.

When run with ampersand (`&`), the output is another pid (bigger). when run without ampersand, the new shell replace the command and is not *forked*.

Replacing the command by:

```
sh -c 'echo $$;set >/tmp/fork_test-$$.env;read'
```

re-running the whole test will generate two files in `/tmp`.

On my desk, I could read:

```
19772
19994
19772
```

So I found two files in `/tmp`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user0 user0 2677 jan 22 00:26 /tmp/fork_test-19772.env
-rw-r--r-- 1 user0 user0 2689 jan 22 00:27 /tmp/fork_test-19994.env
```

If I run: `diff /tmp/fork_test-19*env`, I read:

```
29c29
< SHLVL='0'
---
> SHLVL='1'
46a47
> _='/bin/sh'
```

So the first run, with ampersand is in a *sublevel*.

**Nota:** This was tested under many different [shell](/questions/tagged/shell).

Comment: It has no effect in the forking shell; it has a very big effect in the *forked* shell.

Comment: @chepner Which one??

Comment: The first one; it replaces the forked shell running in the background with `yes` rather than having *that* shell fork in order to run `yes`, wait for it to complete, then exit itself.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure I understand your mean... It's a fork!? Could you explain or address some references?

Comment: Forking is how *any* new process gets started (at least under Unix). For a background job, the shell forks, and the command list terminated by `&` is processed by the background shell.

Comment: @chepner A shell is a background shell, depending on how it is run. Anyway having `exec` or not at begining of a line terminated by an ampersand don't have effect! (If I'm wrong, I would appreciate to learn more!)

Answer (score -1):

The shell forks to run the background process, but that means the *new* shell still needs to fork to run `yes`. Using `exec` eliminates the fork in the subshell.

Comment: Your explanation seemed logical to me, but I tried launching both commands and comparing the resulting process tree with "ps f", and I get the same tree for both (and in both case there does not seem to be an extra "bash" between the interactive shell and "yes").  I tried one more thing : adding "wait" at the end of each command.  In this case, I was surprise to see that it is the case with "exec" that has an extra process (I see two sibling processes for "yes").  Is that consistent with your answer?

Comment: `bash` may be optimized to automatically `exec` in a subshell/subprocess that only needs to run one command. I'm not sure about the case with `wait`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but until you post references explaining your mean, I just think this is totally wrong: Even using [tag:dash] or [tag:busybox] my experiment tend to tell: *there is no difference by using `exec` or not, while using ampersand.*

Comment: What mean *background*? Ampersand **implie** *background* job! Care: `exec` is not same than `nohup`! http://stackoverflow.com/q/15595374/1765658