# Different behaviors of nohup and ampersand (&) in tmux

Tags: linux, bash, tmux, nohup

I learn the difference between `nohup` and `&` from [What's the difference between nohup and ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand)

Based on the following answers,

> There is no difference between these launching methods when the shell is configured in a way where it does not send SIGHUP at all.
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691817

> In case you're using bash, you can use the command shopt | grep hupon to find out whether your shell sends SIGHUP to its child processes or not. If it is off, processes won't be terminated,
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595391

I learn that if `shopt | grep hupon` is off, then `nohup ./foo.sh &` and `./foo.sh &` would be still running after closing the bash sessions.

Indeed, both are running when I check the status via `ps -ef | grep foo.sh`.

However, the behaviors are different when I move to tmux sessions. Firstly, `shopt | grep hupon` is also off in tmux sessions. But the result is that only `nohup ./foo.sh &` can keep running after killing the tmux session.

There should be something different between the tmux session and the bash session, which causes the above different behaviors. Could anyone explain it or give some hints?

Comment: What's the point in doing the `grep`? Just do a `shopt -q huponexit`. If the exit code is 1, the option is off. If it is 0, the option is on.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for unix.stackexchange.com.