# When did HUP stop getting sent and what can I do about it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals

Back in the day when I was young and Unix was the new thing, creating a process that did **not** get killed when you logged out was a challenge. We used the nohup command to protect our persistent processes from the `HUP` signal. If we weren't careful, our processes would get killed when we logged off, or even closed the shell we started them from.

Fast forward to today and I find I am surprised that the default appears to be exactly the opposite. On both Ubuntu and Red Hat systems I find that I can put nearly any process in the background, kill the parent shell, log off, anything and it just keeps going. I see the same behavior with Bash scripts, Python scripts and C programs. I get the same behavior from xterm or ssh sessions.

For example in an xterm or ssh window, type:

```
while [ 1 ]; do date; sleep 10; done > /tmp/out &
```

Now from another window run

```
tail -f /tmp/out
```

Watch it print the date every 10 seconds, then close the original parent shell with Ctrl-D. Still running. Log out and back in. Still running.

Send it a `HUP` signal, it instantly dies.

I can exhibit the same behavior with a Python script or a C program. Sleep or not doesn't matter. For example, this ugly C program behaves the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    while(1) {
        printf("*\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        int i, j, k = 0;
        for(i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
            for(j=0; j < 100000; j++) {
                k += i * j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is completely counter to the ways of my youth. I guess I just didn't notice when it changed? Any historians out there know when this happened? Does `HUP` even get used for this purpose any more?

If indeed this is the current state of things, my question is: **How can I arrange for a process to die when the user logs off or gets disconnected?**

I've got a hack that involves watching for the `ppid` (parent pid) to change but surely there is something more elegant than that.

Comment: huponexit is a bash option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298741/how-bash-handles-the-jobs-when-logout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `huponexit` shell option. You can set this easily with

```
$ shopt -s huponexit
```

Some details from the bash man page:

> The  shell  exits  by  default upon receipt of a SIGHUP.  Before
>   exiting, an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running
>   or
>          stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive the SIGHUP.  To prevent the shell from sending the signal to 
>   a  par-
>          ticular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below) or marked to not
>   receive
>          SIGHUP using disown -h.
>
> If the huponexit shell option has been set with shopt, bash sends a SIGHUP to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits.

Comment: This option appears to explain the unexpected (to me) behavior of both xterms and ssh. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I still get a SIGHUP. A simple way to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "$$"
trap "echo HUPPED $$ > /tmp/willithup" HUP
sleep 1000
```

Then close the terminal emulator. Now back to your question:

> Watch it print the date every 10 seconds, then close the original
>   parent shell with Ctrl-D. Still running. Log out and back in. Still
>   running.

The process doesn't get a HUP when its parent dies. It gets a HUP when it loses the connection to the controlling terminal or when it is explicitly sent a HUP. This happens for example when you logout of SSH.

> If we weren't careful, our processes would get killed when we logged
>   off, or even closed the shell we started them from

For the second one: the shell itself *can* send a HUP to all its children when it exits. However, bash for example has `huponexit` set to false by default. This may well be what has changed. Note that regardless of the huponexit option, **when it receives a HUP the shell also sends a HUP to all its children**.

---

In the words of Stevens:

> A session can have a single controlling terminal. This is usually the
>   terminal device (in the case of a terminal login) or pseudo terminal
>   device (in the case of a network login) on which we log in.
>
> If a modem (or network) **disconnect is detected by the terminal
>   interface the hang-up signal** is sent to the controlling process (the
>   session leader).

---

To further clarify, **the initial HUP** is not sent by the shell. It is sent by the terminal driver. Afterwards the shell "forwards" it to the children. So indeed, a HUP sent by the terminal driver can "cascade". From TLPI:

> **When a controlling process loses its terminal connection, the kernel
>   sends it a SIGHUP signal to inform it of this fact**. (A SIGCONT signal
>   is also sent, to ensure that the process is restarted in case it had
>   been previously stopped by a signal.) Typically, this may occur in two
>   circumstances:
>
> - When a "disconnect" is detected by the terminal driver, indicating a    loss of signal on a modem or terminal line.
> - When a terminal window is closed on a workstation. This occurs because the last open file descriptor for the master side of the pseudoterminal associated with the terminal window is closed.

Comment: I don't if I put it in the background before closing the terminal emulator. The question is about a process running in the background.

Comment: @GaryBishop You can run it "in the background". It will only and always get a HUP when it loses it's connection to the terminal interface.

Comment: bash odes not *always* send a HUP. From my experience more and more systems have had `huponexit` turned off.

Comment: @JimB Read my answer carefully. I never said bash sends the HUP. It's the actual terminal line driver :-)

Comment: @JimB I have added a quote from TLPI :-)

Comment: @cnicutar all true, but I think the OP is referring to the common behavior of the shell itself sending a HUP to all children on exit.

Comment: @JimB I don't know. My `huponexit` is false and the script does receive the HUP.

Comment: I tested with ssh as well as xterm. I don't get HUP in either case. I think huponexit may be the root cause but I've got to test to be sure.

Comment: @GaryBishop This is very interesting. What linux are you using ? What bash version ? How are you testing that you don't get a HUP ?

Comment: @cnicutar I'm running Ubuntu Saucy. GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). I just used ssh to connect to my machine at work. I ran your script and put it in the background with &. Then I disconnected from the machine ending the ssh session. In another window connected to the machine I can see that the sleep 1000 is still running and the willithup file has not been. So losing contact with the control terminal apparently isn't enough to send the signal either.

Comment: @GaryBishop Is it possible your `bash` is ignoring SIGHUP ? Can you `cat /proc/$$/status` and see in `SIG_IGN` if that is the case ?

Comment: SigIgn: 0000000000384004. And typing kill -HUP pid, will kill it instantly. So it isn't ignoring HUP's sent that way.

Comment: @GaryBishop What happens to the children when you `kill -HUP` the bash that forked them ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45960/discussion-between-garybishop-and-cnicutar)