# How to ask a remote server over SSH to run a background job?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm trying to start a long-running process on a remote server, over SSH:

```
$ echo Hello | ssh user@host "cat > /tmp/foo.txt; sleep 100 &"
```

Here, `sleep 100` is a simulation of my long-running process. I want this command to exit instantly, but it waits for 100 seconds. Important to mention that I need the job to receive an input from me (`Hello` in the example above).

Server:

```
$ sshd -?
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Comment: how will the command know there is no more input to arrive? does any output get produced that needs to be captured?

Comment: @jhnc it knows this somehow after 100 seconds :) yes, all the output should be printed to me.

Comment: output locally or remotely?

Comment: @jhnc what is "output locally" in this situation? All output is produced remotely and printed locally. Or I didn't understand the question?

Comment: if it is to be printed locally but you have terminated the ssh connection, how are you expecting the output to get back to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "I want this command to exit instantly" is incompatible with "long-running". Perhaps you mean that you want the long-running command to run in the background.

If output is not immediately needed locally (ie. it can be retrieved by another ssh in future), then `nohup` is simple:

```
echo hello |
ssh user@host '
    cat >/tmp/foo.txt;
    nohup </dev/null >cmd.out 2>cmd.err cmd &
'
```

If output must be received locally as the command runs, you can background ssh itself using `-f`:

```
echo hello |
ssh -f user@host '
    cat >/tmp/foo.txt;
    cmd
' >cmd.out 2>cmd.err
```

Comment: you are right, the problem was that the background job was "holding" the stdout and stderr streams. thanks!

Comment: @jhnc - in your first snippet, why do you need the `nohup`? It seems to be working without..?

Comment: @YoavKlein You are correct. `nohup` may not be necessary in this situation (it would be needed if `ssh -t` were used, for example), but it is always safe to use `nohup` instead of trying to decide in any particular situation if sighup is expected. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21294283/10971581